# Replace value of img src tag in HTML string

Tags: ios

I am getting an HTML string from server which has `<img src="data:image/png;base64, BASE64_STRING/>` tag and I want to change add my `base64` string to this string. How to do that?

Comment: you want to convert html string to base64 string ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use JS to get the proper DOM element and change the `src` property. See the `WKWebView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

1. Load the HTML into the `WKWebView`
2. execute JS to change the `src` attribute of your `img` tag using `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)`

You can also use regexp. See `NSRegularExpression` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression).